# Multi-Thread & Active Directory

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, active-directory

I am writing an application that pulls computer names from Active Directory. The process is suh-low.

```
Dim childEntry As DirectoryEntry
    Dim ParentEntry As New DirectoryEntry()
    Try
        ParentEntry.Path = "WinNT:"
        For Each childEntry In ParentEntry.Children
            Dim newNode As New TreeNode(childEntry.Name)
            Select Case childEntry.SchemaClassName
                Case "Domain"
                    Dim ParentDomain As New TreeNode(childEntry.Name)
                    TreeView1.Nodes.AddRange(New TreeNode() {ParentDomain})

                    Dim SubChildEntry As DirectoryEntry
                    Dim SubParentEntry As New DirectoryEntry()
                    SubParentEntry.Path = "WinNT://" & childEntry.Name
                    For Each SubChildEntry In SubParentEntry.Children
                        Dim newNode1 As New TreeNode(SubChildEntry.Name)
                        Select Case SubChildEntry.SchemaClassName
                            Case "Computer"
                                ParentDomain.Nodes.Add(newNode1)
                        End Select
                    Next
            End Select
        Next
    Catch Excep As Exception
        MsgBox("Error While Reading Directories")

    Finally
        ParentEntry = Nothing
    End Try
```

So question time.

1.) Would it speed up the process by running this code in another thread?

2.) If so, how would I go about doing that? (Keep in mind, I've never pulled off multi-threading successfully)

Thanks all!!

Comment: No - running in a separate thread will not make it execute any faster (it might even be slower). What it will do is not freeze the UI while it is doing the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not supprised in the slightest that is slow! If you look into the [`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace you'll find a much simpler and faster way to get things like lists of computer names.

Comment: I thought AccountManagement would help return users and edit users not domain computers...

Comment: @improv_monkey It can do both.